# Are cherry tree roots causing my patio to subside

Tags: trees, roots

Next door have a 30 foot high cherry tree which is about 10 feet away from my fence. The branches overhang my garden. Could this be the reason for my patio, which is underneath the overhanging branches, subsiding?

Answer (score 4):

Tree roots add to the soil volume. If they cause a visible change, they lift parts of my flagstone walkways.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Cherry trees in particular are prone to putting out long roots just under the top surface of the soil - if the tree is 30 feet high, its likely there are roots under your patio which may well extend much further than the crown of the tree. Obviously, roots get thicker over time, so yes, it's possible the cherry tree has caused an issue.

UPDATE: You asked if a cherry tree can cause subsidence. It is possible, but depending how old your house is and how long the tree has been in situ, the likelihood is hard to estimate, because removing established trees can sometimes cause such damage. If the tree was in place when the houses were built, subsidence is much less likely. That said, however, no tree should be planted within 40 feet of any structure or house as a minimum. Further formation here https://askinglot.com/can-a-cherry-tree-damage-foundation

Comment: Would they cause subsidence?

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Hi Bamboo - here in the US, if we stuck to the no-trees-within-40-feet rule then residential areas of most cities would have few to no trees :) Typically, streets here are within 25-30 feet of the houses, with trees planted on an eight-foot-wide terrace between street and sidewalk, so trees are within 25 feet of the houses. Of course, there are many regional variations to this style of planting. Backyards/gardens are often only 40-60 feet long and maybe 60-80 feet wide. Suburban yards are typically much larger, though.

Comment: We do have that type of arrangement in the UK - London Plane trees for instance, planted at the edge of a pavement next to a road, but any housing is usually set back a minimum of 35 feet from the trees and they are  quite severely pollarded every other year.  Other roads have a mix of smaller trees, but, as I say, never cherry trees because of the disruptive surface roots. Narrow roads don't have trees planted in the pavements at all, the houses might only be 6 feet or less from the pavement (sidewalk).

Comment: You know, I've never seen a pollarded tree in the US - and I've been in 26 states. Well, not intentionally pollarded (just pollarded due to laziness on the part of a homeowner who gave up cutting a tree down after removing its limbs). I have seen them in southern Germany, though, although they weren't common. Are they that common in the UK?

Comment: Not uncommon in built up areas like London where they line busy roads - if they weren't pollarded regularly, they'd grow together over the road forming a dark tunnel and tall vehicles like double  decker buses would need to force their way through branches and foliage. Some might just be regularly pruned hard rather than actual pollarding, depends on the circumstances.